# How does copying and pasting realise and reveal a webpage's formatting?

Tags: website, copy-paste, libreoffice, microsoft-office-2013

Preface: This question is motivated by [the last paragraph by a Francophone](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14331/1995) at French SE.
Also, I use 'realise' to mean ['actuate' or 'actualise' or 'effectuate'](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/effect?s=t).

In the aforesaid post, I publicised my trouble with reading websites like [CNTRL.FR](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/precipiter) that seem to lack any formatting, and so seems too muddled to read. Then the generous Francophone user advised that the latent formatting  would be realised and revealed by  copying and pasting this entangled website into (the program) Libreoffice.

1. Copying and pasting into Microsoft Word, failed to realise and reveal CNTRL's latent formatting. Why? Why does the advice above fail for any Microsoft Office program?

2. Can the above realisation of formatting be achieved with Microsoft Office? How?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "it failed".  Without knowing more about how it failed (what actions you took, what the result was, error messages, etc.), it's impossible for us to explain it. :)

Comment: Can you try using the hotkey <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>? The shift should paste it without formatting.

Comment: N'y a-t-il pas une fonction d'affichage de la page au format HTML quelque part dans Word ? (Définitivement linuxien, je n'ai pas de VM XP disponible sous la main)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Sorry for the confusion. I edited my OP. Better?

Comment: @MattClark To clarify, I need and desire the formatting. I tried to copy from the website as usual, and then pressed `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `V` in MS Word, but nothing occurred.